# Did Sandburg have anything against Omaha?

Tags: poetry, carl-sandburg

Specifically:

> I am riding on a limited express, one of the crack trains of the nation.
>
> Hurtling across the prairie into blue haze and dark air go fifteen all-steel coaches holding a thousand people.
>
> (All the coaches shall be scrap and rust and all the men and women laughing in the diners and sleepers shall pass to ashes.)
>
> I ask a man in the smoker where he is going and he answers: “Omaha.”
>
> <sub>Sandburg: [Limited](http://www.theotherpages.org/poems/sandb02.html)</sub>

It's a profound poem wrapped in a shell of the everyday, and it's title is perhaps taken as a commentary on the mundane mindset.

I wouldn't think Sandburg means anything by relating Omaha specifically to non-existence, possibly the name of the city just scans, or represents the heartland, but then I think of Strindberg naming his famous play about marriage "[The Dance of Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Plague_of_1518)" and wonder...

**Q: Did Sandburg have any negative feelings about the wonderful city of Omaha?**

Comment: I don't think he's identifying Omaha with *scrap and rust* and *ashes*. The point of the last line is that people don't realize they're headed for oblivion; they just think they're going to a nice normal place like Omaha.

Comment: @MissMonicaE *(even the way you phrase it makes Omaha sound like oblivion;)*  I suspect there were also practical considerations in the choice--"Omaha" is a dactyl and a strong way to end a poem b/c the stress is on that first syllable--compare to substituting "Chicago", which has the same number of syllables but doesn't rhythmically convey the same sense of finality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read Sandburg's poem, ["Omaha"](https://www.poemhunter.com/poem/omaha/). I think you'll see that he does not:  "...Omaha works to get the world a breakfast."

> Omaha, the roughneck, feeds armies,
>   Eats and swears from a dirty face.
>   Omaha works to get the world a breakfast.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the last stanza of the poem, as well as a link to its full text, to your answer. I think that makes it more credible. Is there anything else in Sandburg's works that pertains to his feelings towards Omaha?